# Pygame if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN() TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

The code is meant to quickly exit pygame by tapping escape.

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN():
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

This code errors with this:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    G:\Code\JonSocket\keyboard.py   19      
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Very similar code works when,

```
event.type == pygame.QUIT
```

Is there a difference between pygame.QUIT + pygame.KEYDOWN?

Thanks.

Comment: Minimal reproduction case: `x = 1; x()`. Make sure to listen to the error messages - this is too localized and very duplicated.

Comment: Thank-you for the answers. I got it solved, like the comments say, Change it to
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

Comment: `pygame.quit` is a function but `pygame.QUIT` is an int. You can verify this with `print(type(pygame.QUIT))`

Comment: "Very similar code works" - no it doesn't. pygame.QUIT() throws the same error. pygame.QUIT is an integer (12 to be exact). pygame.quit() is a function. Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in the line

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN():
```

`pygame.KEYDOWN` is not a function but just an integer constant.

Change it to

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```